# inserting values when null

Tags: sql

I have two tables like

**Student:**

```
roll    Name
1       A
2       B
3       C
```

**Mark**

```
roll    Mark
1       85
3       95
```

I want a output like

```
roll    Name    Grade
1       A       A
2       B       F
3       C       A+
```

I have tried this query

```
select Stdent.Roll,Stdent.Name,Grade= case 
when (Mark between 0 and 79) then ('F')
when (Mark between 80 and 89) then ('A')
when (Mark between 90 and 100) then ('A+') end  
from Mark 
right join Stdent 
on Mark.roll=Stdent.Roll 
order by Stdent.Roll
```

Output shows null in 2nd row of grade column. But I want it to be F.

Comment: I have added the SQL tag but I don't know which dialect is this.

Answer (score 1):

```
select Stdent.Roll,Stdent.Name,Grade= case 
when (func(Mark,0) between 0 and 79) then ('F')
when (Mark between 80 and 89) then ('A')
when (Mark between 90 and 100) then ('A+') end  
from Mark 
right join Stdent 
on Mark.roll=Stdent.Roll 
order by Stdent.Roll
```

You should use ISNULL instead of func if you are using sql server, if oracle nvl. Check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp) page for others.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle `Mark` being `NULL` in your case statement:

```
SELECT  Student.Roll,
        Student.Name,
        Grade = CASE 
                    WHEN Mark.Mark BETWEEN 0 AND 79 OR Mark.Mark IS NULL THEN 'F'
                    WHEN Mark.Mark BETWEEN 80 AND 89 THEN 'A'
                    WHEN Mark.Mark BETWEEN 90 AND 100 THEN 'A+'
                END  
FROM    Mark 
        RIGHT JOIN Student 
            ON Mark.roll=Student.Roll 
ORDER BY Student.Roll
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select Stdent.Roll,Stdent.Name,Grade= case 
when (IsNull(Mark, 0) between 0 and 79) then ('F')
when (Mark between 80 and 89) then ('A')
when (Mark between 90 and 100) then ('A+') end  
from Mark 
right join Stdent 
on Mark.roll=Stdent.Roll 
order by Stdent.Roll
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Stdent.Roll,Stdent.Name,Grade= case 
 when (NVL(Mark,0) between 0 and 79) then ('F')
 when (Mark between 80 and 89) then ('A')
 when (Mark between 90 and 100) then ('A+') end  
from Mark 
 right join Stdent 
 on Mark.roll=Stdent.Roll 
order by Stdent.Roll
```

Use NVL function to handle null values